# The statement will be terminated SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, insert

I've got a problem with a SQL Server query.

I already looked on StackOverflow about that mistake. It supposed to be that the length of one of the column is not long enough, but in that case, it's impossible.

The table is like this:

```
id numeric (10),
project varchar(10),
name varchar(50),
path varchar(500),
categorie(50)
```

And here's the mistake :

```
The statement has been terminated.[ 
INSERT INTO [2tlm_spec].[links] (project, name, path, categorie) VALUES('2tlm',      
'Project Definition','http://caevgl03.caecorp.cae.com/projects/2tlm/2tlm_proj_def.htm',   
'Project Info') ]
```

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: As explained in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3053669/what-causes-sql-server-to-return-the-message-the-statement-has-been-terminated) there is probably a previous error that isn't visible to PHP. The easy way to troubleshoot is to copy and paste your code into SSMS and run it there (and/or trace your code with SQL Profiler). If this doesn't help, please post a complete test script including a full `CREATE TABLE` statement; if `id` is defined `NOT NULL` then you will get this error, but since you haven't shown your full table definition that's just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In that case, the problem is the `id numeric(18, 0),not NULL)`

If you change it where it can be `null`, The sql statement will be executed properly.